# Laravel debugging 404 routes

Tags: php, laravel, http-status-code-404, laravel-routing

Ok, the full `routes.php` file that I use... I just pasted it here: http://pastebin.com/kaCP3NwK

### routes.php

```
//The route group for all other requests needs to validate admin, model, and add assets
Route::group(array('before' => 'validate_admin|validate_model'), function()
{
    //Model Index
    Route::get('admin/(:any)', array(
        'as' => 'admin_index',
        'uses' => 'admin@index'
    ));
```

administrator config:

```
...
'models' => array(
'news' => array(
    'title' => 'News',
    'single' => 'news',
    'model' => 'AdminModels\\News',
),
...
```

links generator:

```
@foreach (Config::get('administrator.models') as $key => $model)
    @if (Admin\Libraries\ModelHelper::checkPermission($key))
        <?php $key = is_numeric($key) ? $model : $key; ?>
        <li>
            {{ HTML::link(URL::to_route('admin_index', array($key)), $model['title']) }}
        </li>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

### controllers/admin.php

```
public function action_index($modelName)
{
    //first we get the data model
    $model = ModelHelper::getModelInstance($modelName);

    $view = View::make("admin.index",
        array(
            "modelName" => $modelName,
        )
    );

    //set the layout content and title
    $this->layout->modelName = $modelName;
    $this->layout->content = $view;
}
```

So, when accessing `http://example.com/admin/news` the `news` is sent to `action_index`... but for some reason it doesn't get there and it returns `404`

Comment: Is your bundle registered to handle routes? Does [http://mysite.com/admin](http://mysite.com/admin) load your index page?
http://laravel.com/docs/routing#bundle-routes

Comment: @ChrisHendry Yes, everything works by default... and I already added a new router to bundle's file, a route for uploading images and it works great

Comment: does it still 404 if you debug with an anonymous function and return in the route? (without trying to point to the controller/method)

Comment: If Laravel is unable to find a route, it returns a prettier error than the server.  Are you getting the Laravel 404 or the server's 404?

Comment: I'm getting Laravels's 404 error... if it were to be more of a apache url rewriting issue, that would've been easier to resolve... I'm sure about that :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notice that I defined the following `'model' => 'AdminModels\\News',`

when actually my `namespace` register was `Admin\Models`, so setting it to `'model' => 'Admin\Models\\News',` for my issue for the 404

Answer (score 3):

Routes are evaluated in the order that they're registered, so the (:any) route should be last.  You're being sent (I think) to admin@index -- if that function isn't defined yet, that's why you're getting a 404.

Comment: There must not be an "action_index" in w0rldart's administrator bundle's admin controller. That would explain the 404

Comment: Actually, `action_index` is defined. You can view it here https://github.com/FrozenNode/Laravel-Administrator/blob/master/controllers/admin.php

Answer (score 2):

Not related to the question, but if anyone (like me) comes here to find clues why a Laravel application displays a 404, here are some reasons:

- Models not found in database that are specified in the URL
- You have setup incorrect route model bindings in RouteServiceProvider (as I did when I stumbled over this answer). Example: Route::model('user', Tenant::class); when it should be User::class
- Some middleware returns 404 (e.g. via "abort(404)")
- The corresponding controller returns 404
- The controller method (or namespace) is not found (This is the answer for this question.)

Comment: This list fixed it for me, thanks :) Made a mistake in the RouteServiceProvider.